# Why does the permutation importance box plot look strange? How to plot a horizontal bar plot instead

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using a `RandomForestClassifier` and using the `permutation_importance` plot by scikit-learn to observe feature importance which can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html). However my box plot looks strange, with seemingly no lower bound for the second variable. Also for some variables there are just two dots and no box. What is going on with this? Below is the code

```
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
result = permutation_importance(rf, X_test, y_test, n_repeats=10,
                                random_state=42, n_jobs=2)
sorted_idx = result.importances_mean.argsort()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(result.importances[sorted_idx].T,
           vert=False, labels=X_test.columns[sorted_idx])
ax.set_title("Permutation Importances (test set)")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the plot:
[image]

I have blacked out the variables for privacy. I would like to plot it as a horizontal bar chart without needing range, standard deviation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a horizontal bar plot using mean values of the output of permutation importance.

## bar plot for the example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html)

```
result = permutation_importance(rf, X_test, y_test, n_repeats=10,
                                random_state=42, n_jobs=2)
sorted_idx = result.importances_mean.argsort()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(X_test.columns[sorted_idx], result.importances[sorted_idx].mean(axis=1).T)
ax.set_title("Permutation Importances (test set)")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

To understand the output of your box plot visuals, consider the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.boxplot([[0,33,10,10,10,10,10],
             [0,10,10,10,10,10,10],
             [11,11,9,10,10,20]], vert=False)
```

[image]